# How do i move this block?

Tags: css, position, css-position, word-wrap

I am new to coding so I'm sorry if this is a basic question.  I am trying to put text on the left side of the screen and a form on the right side of the screen.  I have managed to position both items accurately, but for some reason the text is being forced to wrap incorrectly.

I am trying to make the text appear like this:

"Hire the talent you won't
be 
able to afford tomorrow!"

However, something in the CSS is forcing the text to wrap like this:

"Hire the talent you won't
 
be
able to afford tomorrow!"

I think it has to do with the way I am positioning the form to the right of the text.  Here is the CSS that is controlling the text:

```
.SimpleText { width:928px; margin:50px auto  auto  auto; padding-top: 18px; height:90px;} 
.SimpleText h2 { color:#fff; font:normal 30px  Georgia, "Times New Roman", Times, serif;     padding:0 0 0 40px; margin:0; background:url(images/h2_bg_simple_text.gif) left no-repeat;}<br>
.SimpleText p { color:#bbe2ed; font:normal 11px  Georgia, "Times New Roman", Times, serif; padding:0 0 0 60px; margin:0;}
```

and here is the css that governs the form:

```
#formtest{ position: relative; float: right; left: 100px;}
```

and here is how it appears in the html page:

```
  <div class="SimpleText">
      <div id="formtest">

          <!--form is here !-->

      </div>

    <h2>Hire the talent you won't be <br />able to afford tomorrow!</h2>
    <p>Great talent you can depend upon</p>

  </div>
```

How can I fix it so that it wraps correctly?  Thank you.

Also, the form is inside  of an iframe.  Here is the code for the iframe:

```
<script type="text/javascript">document.write(unescape("%3Ciframe id=\"fb_iframe\"     src=\"formio.php" + window.location.search + "\" width=\"560\" height=\"677\"allowtransparency=\"true\" scrolling=\"no\" frameborder=\"0\"%3E&lt;a href=\"new_Form.php\" title=\"new_Form\"&gt;blan&lt;/a&gt;%3C/iframe%3E"));</script>
<noscript>
<iframe width="560" height="677" style="border:none; background:transparent;   overflow:hidden;"
 id="formfas" src="axyform.html">
&lt;a href="formio.php" title="new_Form"&gt;m&lt;/a&gt;
</iframe>
</noscript>
```

Comment: Can you add the HTML for the form?

Comment: The form is inside an Iframe.  I'll add the iframe code to the main question above.  Thanks.  I'm doing it right now

Comment: I have added the iframe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can solve this issue by extending the width of `.SimpleText`. For example:

```
.SimpleText {
    width:968px;
}
```

[JS Fiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/pEzg7/)

Comment: Great, thank you.  I tried voting up your answer but i don't have a high enough reputation yet.